# How to use findstr in powershell to search for a string in the whole drive?

Tags: powershell

So I received the task of finding a specific log file in a cyber security lab. I am meant to find the log file for a password tool which contains the information for a man called Alan Jones (username alan.jones).

I have been given the clue of using the findstr command, however, this is only useful for searching through one directory.

Is there a way to use findstr to get powershell to search through the whole drive for a specific string?

Comment: Findstr has `/s` switch for [searching subdirectories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr)

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to use PowerShell I'd recommend you stick with the native cmdlets over using `findstr`, `Select-String` can do what you want:

`Get-ChildItem C:\*.log -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "alan\.jones"`

For more information on Select-String run
`Get-Help Select-String -Online`

Comment: thanks so much, would it just output the file paths in powershell after running? and why the "\" before the surname?

Comment: It'll return an object with Filename, Line, LineNumber etc as properties. The `-Pattern` parameter defaults to RegEx, hence escaping `"."`.

Comment: Nice. As an alternative to escaping the `.`, you can use the `-SimpleMatch` switch to perform _literal_ matching.

Comment: `-filter *.log` would be faster

Answer (score 3):

**If speed matters, stick with [`findstr.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr)**, and use the `/s` switch to perform a recursive search, as [vonPryz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/503046/vonpryz) suggests:

```
findstr /s /m /c:alan.jones c:\*.log
```

- `/s` makes `findstr` search recursively; that is, the input directory as well as as all its subdirectories and their subdirectories, ... are searched.
- `/c:...` looks for the search string *literally* (default is to treat it as a *regular expression*, in which case `.` is a metacharacter (a character with special meanings) that matches *any* input character);
- `/m` prints only the *paths* of the files in which the search string is found.

Note:

- **`findstr.exe` *invariably* includes *hidden* directories and files in the search**.
- **`findstr.exe` *quietly ignores* inaccessible directories**, i.e., directories that cannot be accessed due to lack of permissions.

**Caveat**: The string will only be found in files that use **ASCII character encoding or one of its supersets (ANSI, OEM, UTF-8)**; to match *all* of the latter, the search string itself must comprise ASCII-range characters only; e.g, it mustn't contain accented letters such as `é`.

---

**If you need to also recognize additional character encodings**, notably UTF-16LE ("Unicode"), **use `Select-String`** in combination with `Get-ChildItem -Recurse`, but note that **it will be noticeably slower**.

On the plus side, [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string):

- supports more powerful [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions) (.NET's)
- offers additional features
- outputs objects that complement the lines found with rich metadata, notably what parts of the line matched; access the `.Line` property to extract the line only; `.Path` contains the full path of the input file.

By default, the search argument passed to `-Pattern` is interpreted as a regular expression, as with `findstr`.
**Add the `-SimpleMatch` switch to perform a *literal* string search** instead, which not only avoids the need to `\`-escape special characters such as `.` in the search string, but also speeds up the operation.

As [js2010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6654942/js2010), suggests, another way to speed up the command is to use the `-Filter` parameter (e.g., `-Filter *.log`) rather than including the wildcard pattern in the `-Path` parameter argument (`-Path *.log`).

**If you need to include *hidden* directories and files, add the `-Force` switch**; by default `Get-ChildItem` and `Get-Item` ignore them.

Given that you're searching the entire drive, **you're likely to encounter directories you won't be able to access due to lack of permissions**, especially if you don't run with elevation and also include `-Force` (but even with elevation (running as admin) access-denied errors can occur).

**Use `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to silence errors**; if you need to inspect errors later, also add something like `-ev errs` (`-ev` is short for `-ErrorVariable`), which collects the errors that occur in variable `$errs`.

To put it all together:

```
# Running with elevation (as admin) lessens the risk of access-denied errors.
# Add -Force to include hidden dirs. and files.
Get-ChildItem -Recurse C:\ -Filter *.log -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ev errs | 
  Select-String -Pattern alan.jones -SimpleMatch
```

---

Finally, note that `Select-String` can *itself* target files, but only those in a *single* directory; also, hidden files are *invariably ignored*.

E.g., to only search the current directory's `*.log` files:

```
Select-String -Pattern alan.jones -SimpleMatch -Path *.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to see if there was some nice parallel way to do it.  Here's an interesting yet problematic script from *Windows Powershell in Action*.  It makes a job for each path you give it.  Unfortunately, relative paths don't work in jobs.

```
# Search-FilesInParallel.ps1

# relative paths in jobs are relative to ~\documents
# select-string -list only shows first match in file
# select-string in jobs outputs invisibly
# wait-job -any finishes if any job finishes
param (
  [parameter(mandatory=$true, position=0)]
  $Pattern,

  [parameter(mandatory=$true, position=1)]
  [string[]]
  $Path,

  [parameter()]
  $Filter = "*.txt",

  [parameter()]
  [switch]
  $Any
)
$jobid = [Guid]::NewGuid().ToString() 
$jobs = foreach ($element in $path)
{
  write-host "start-job -name Srch{$jobid}"  # added this
  Start-Job -name "Srch{$jobid}" -scriptblock {  # moved dollar sign to "$jobid"
    param($pattern, $path, $filter, $any)
    Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Filter $filter | # added "|"
    Select-String -list:$any $pattern | select *  # added "| select *"
  } -ArgumentList $pattern,$element,$filter,$any
}
Wait-Job -any:$any $jobs | Receive-Job # -any: an unsuccessful job could finish 1st
Remove-Job -force $jobs
```

Compile an example list of folders:

```
 $list = ls -r \ -filter *.log -ea 0 | select -expand directoryname -ea 0 | sort -u
```

Run it with a pattern I know can be found:

```
.\Search-FilesInParallel.ps1 -path $list -filter *.log -pattern '09/01/2017 23:35:30'
```

Output without the exceptions:

```
IgnoreCase : True
LineNumber : 2
Line       : INFO:   09/01/2017 23:35:30
Filename   : DPINST.LOG
Path       : C:\Windows\DPINST.LOG
Pattern    : 09/01/2017 23:35:30
Context    :
Matches    : {09/01/2017 23:35:30}
RunspaceId : 4a9634be-7217-4225-8bcc-bfd326cf722e

IgnoreCase : True
LineNumber : 37
Line       : INFO:   09/01/2017 23:35:30
Filename   : DPINST.LOG
Path       : C:\Windows\DPINST.LOG
Pattern    : 09/01/2017 23:35:30
Context    :
Matches    : {09/01/2017 23:35:30}
RunspaceId : 4a9634be-7217-4225-8bcc-bfd326cf722e

IgnoreCase : True
LineNumber : 39
Line       : INFO:   09/01/2017 23:35:30
Filename   : DPINST.LOG
Path       : C:\Windows\DPINST.LOG
Pattern    : 09/01/2017 23:35:30
Context    :
Matches    : {09/01/2017 23:35:30}
RunspaceId : 4a9634be-7217-4225-8bcc-bfd326cf722e
```